# memory access: why it doesn't crash and how to enforce it?

Tags: c++

I expect the following code would generate certain memory access fault but it doesn't. Is there way to enforce it during compilation?

```
#include <iostream>
class B {};
class D : public B
{ public: int d; };

using namespace std;

main()
{
    B *pB = new B;
    ((D*)pB)->d = 2;
    cout << ((D*)pB)->d << endl;
}
```

As I understand, casting pointer to D does not change memory allocation so accessing "d" should be illegal, right?

Comment: This is not well-formed C++.

Comment: @Kerrek SB - Not to mention that it is *horrible* C++; `using namespace ...`, raw pointers rather than smart pointers, C style casts, incorrect `main` declaration, sub-optimal formatting (arguable, sure), `endl` used where `\n` would do... Ohh yes, and then there's the UB that wrecks everything. Its actually somewhat impressive that so much fail could be crammed into so few lines. (Sorry OP)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, accessing `d` *is* illegal, and your code has undefined behaviour.

There is no concept of "crash" in C++, so it does not make sense to ask for a portable way to create a "crash". If the behaviour of a program is undefined, it is not portable, and the language rules do not tell you what the program is doing.

Comment: That's exactly the second part of my question: how to enforce the checking.

Comment: @user180574: Nowhere in your question are you asking that.

Comment: as in the title

Comment: @user180574: Can you please a) make your question self-contained (the title isn't part of the question), and b) be specific about what exactly you want? But be warned, we can generally only provide guidance for C++ programs with defined behaviour. It's very hard to guarantee that any one specific thing will happen when anything can happen.

Comment: @user180574 To quote the standard "Undefined behavior: behavior for which this International Standard imposes no requirements.". So, since the compiler is allowed to do **anything** to your *entire* program once you invoke UB, the answer is simply "you cannot". The solution is to never invoke UB (by knowing the rules and what you are doing).

Answer (score 0):

It is illegal, but you are casting which tells the compiler you know what you are doing (don't do this without knowing the consequences) and cthat converts your pointer from B* to a D* while still actually being a B obhect at the location pointed to. So the results here are **UNDEFINED** since you are accessing out of bounds.

Also it would be good to prefer C++ style casts, vs C style casts (you are using a C-style cast) as they are generally a bit safer.

Comment: It's not just the result of the access that is undefined. The behaviour of the entire program is undefined.

Comment: Yes the entire program will be undefined, but the reason, is from the cast and attempt to access something that may or may not exist.

Comment: The cast does **not** convert the `B` object into a `D` object. If it did, that would (probably) be fine. What it does is convert the `B*` into a `D*` which still points to the original `B` object, and that's asking for trouble.

Comment: Good point, I was not very clear with that although it is what I meant, I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing usually won't cause a crash because of the way that memory allocation is typically handled behind the scenes.

And there are third party products that can check for errors of this kind (a buffer overrun in this case). Just search for "memory debuggers c++". Most tools for Windows are commercial, but there may be free ones available.

Comment: Please clarify.  There is only room allocated for an instance of class B. If class D is bigger than B, then memory is accessed that wasn't allocated.  There is no information about how the memory for the program is allocated.  If the OS only allocates as necessary, then trouble exists.